# Can't use "ç" as a keybinding in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to move the navigation keys in normal mode 1 key to the right and because I have a portuguese layout keyboard the key that's next to L is "ç".

when i try to save

```
:nnoremap ç l
```

it gets saved as

```
:nnoremap ? l
```

I have tried using  (alt + g makes a ç) but that doesn't seem to work. 
Thanks

Comment: `:set encoding? fileencoding? termencoding?`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Vim, do you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: `:` brings `vim` to [EX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-mode, i.e. it's vim's command line. The command [`set`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set) sets, unsets, inverts vim options; it also displays option values if `?` is appended to the option name. With the command `:set encoding? fileencoding? fileencodings? termencoding?` I'm trying to see what `vim` currently thinks of its encoding (character set) settings. It could improperly configured and recodes `ç` to `?`

Comment: when I use that command i get:
`encoding=utf-8 fileencoding= termencoding=` (the last 2 are just empty)

Comment: Hmm, looks god.